# Generating two different numbers not close to each other in Python

Tags: python

I know how to generate different random numbers in a specific range but i want to choose a random number out of two numbers that are not close to each other and there are numbers between them that i don't want to be included in the generation process.
for example: i don't want one to be generated in this command.

```
play = (random.randint(0, 2)), (random.randint(0, 2))
```

Comment: `random.choice([0, 2])`?

Comment: @tobias_k what will that do ?

Comment: Give you either 0 or 2.

Comment: @Mark what do you mean by *that are not close to each other*... in your example - even if we pretend that `1` is somehow excluded, `0` and `2` are what I'd call *close* to each other... and there's always the chance you'll get 2 `0`s or 2 `2`s...

Comment: Your `play` seems to be a tuple of two numbers. Is that intended? Is there any restriction to that tuple, e.g. that the two numbers should not be the same?

Comment: @JonClements i specified that i don't want the one to be printed in the example but generaly what if only want the compiler to choose between 5 or 999 or 100000 only ?

Comment: 0 and 2 nanometers are far apart when you think of distances on the order of pico meters. 0 and 2 million kilometers are very close when you speak of light years. What is your definition of close?

Comment: @Sheldore I think from the context it is pretty clear that OP is just talking about integer numbers that are not next to each other, where `randint` won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of values to choose from is small, and the values are discrete (i.e. not "between 0 to 1 or between 2 to 3") the easiest way would be to use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.choice), which will select either of the provided values, i.e. `random.choice([0, 2])` does not mean "chose a number between 0 and 2" but "chose either 0 or 2".

```
play = (random.choice([0, 2]), random.choice([0, 2]))
```

Of course, you can also provide more than two values, and those do not have to be integers, so you could also use this variant, which may or may not be clearer:

```
play = random.choice([(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)])
```

If you also want the two parts of `play` to be different numbers, you can modify this accordingly:

```
play = random.choice([(0, 2), (2, 0)])
```

Or use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.sample) to select `k` distinct values from a given population:

```
play = random.sample([0, 2], 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to check the difference between your two values such as

```
diff = abs(play[0] - play[1])
```

This will yield the difference as a positive number. It is up to you if you want to check if the number should be a static value ( `if diff < 10` ) or a percentage ( `if diff < play[0] / 10 and diff < play[1] / 10` ).

Once you have the value, you can either brute force the values ( not the best, should only be used if your range of possible values is very big and the probabilities of have to get an other value is low. Else, choose a safer method ).
The other possibility is to add an other value ( random or not ) such as :

```
play[1] = (play[1] + random.randint(0, max_value)) % max_value
```

Using a modulo with your max value will ensure that you do not end up will an overflow or an other similar issue.

There are many more ways to do what you need, these are just two simple examples.